# Add property decorator to partial class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a partial class in a dbml file.

```
public partial class Comment
  string email
```

Clearly I can't put a decorator on it because this is a generated file and you shouldn't make change in it yourself.

So I created another partial class;

```
public partial class Comment
  [IsEmailAddress]
  string email
```

The above doesn't work but I need something like that so I can validate the email address on the model.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should used `MetadataType` like so...

```
[MetadataType(typeof(CommentMetadata))]
public partial class Comment {

}

public class CommentMetadata {
    [IsEmailAddress]
    public string email {get;set;}
}
```

That will allow you to add your attributes without it being overridden the next time you update your models.

Comment: Just make sure you don't add the `MetadataType` tag to the dbml partial class :)